# Wait for script to load

Tags: javascript, jquery

Try the following code in your browser's console:

```
var script= document.createElement('script');
script.type= 'text/javascript';
script.src= 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js';
script.async = true;
document.body.appendChild(script);

console.log($);
```

Then wait a few seconds and do this again:

```
console.log($);
```

So it takes a while for jQuery to load. I tried [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701746/load-jquery-file-dynamically-and-execute-it), which seems to be the consensus of all related questions:

```
+function loadScript(url, callback)
{
    // Adding the script tag to the head as suggested before
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = url;

    // Then bind the event to the callback function.
    // There are several events for cross browser compatibility.
    script.onreadystatechange = callback;
    script.onload = callback;

    // Fire the loading
    head.appendChild(script);
}("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js", function(){console.log($);});
```

And once again it doesn't work ... 
[image]
The first `console.log($)` should give the correct result. **What can I do to execute a function as soon as jQuery has loaded *and executed***?

(Background: I'm writing a Chrome extension to fix formatting on a page that doesn't use jQuery.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113366/load-jquery-with-javascript-and-use-jquery

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://i.imgur.com/5e92Yco.png) doesn't seem to work for me. Could you execute that same code in your browser's console and give me a screenshot?

Comment: Can someone explain why my code doesn't work?

Comment: I think you have missed to call the function. check here [http://snag.gy/ElXTY.jpg](http://snag.gy/ElXTY.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function loadScript(url, callback){
    var foo1 = document.createElement('script');
    foo1.type = 'text/javascript';
    foo1.setAttribute('src', url);

    foo1.onreadystatechange = callback;
    foo1.onload = callback;

    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    head.appendChild(foo1, head);
}
loadScript(('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') +'code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js', function(){
    console.log($);
});
```